# replaces multiple occurances of a character (except for first and last) in a python string

Tags: python, regex

I want to know what is the most concise way to achieve the following in python:

Given a string with a *minimum* of 2 ',' characters (e.g., 'abc,123,#$@5,dg'). I want to create a new string with the first and last ',' characters from the original string intact, but replaces every other occurrences of ',' with the '_' character.

Here are some sample inputs/outputs:

**Input:**

```
str1 = 'abc,1,2201-3'
```

**Output:**

```
str2 = 'abc,1,2201-3'
```

**Input:**

```
str1 = '$2a$10$.XfjKl/,abcd, 1, ##, s, for free,2-3-4'
```

**Output:**

```
str2 = '$2a$10$.XfjKl/,abcd_ 1_ ##_ s_ for free,2-3-4'
```

One way to do this is to split the string into a list by the ',' character, use '_' to join the middle element of the list, then just create a new string using the first element + ',' + middle elements + ',' + last element. Is there a more concise way of doing this (maybe using Regex)?

Comment: i think your first example is wrong

Comment: first example has 2 ',' characters, but I don't want to replace them. I only want to replace all ',' characters besides the first and last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str1 = '$2a$10$.XfjKl/,abcd, 1, ##, s, for free,2-3-4'
parts = str1.split(',')
str2 = '{},{},{}'.format(parts[0],'_'.join(parts[1:-1]),parts[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution with regex, try this:

```
    import re
    str1 = '$2a$10$.XfjKl/,abcd, 1, ##, s, for free,2-3-4'
    p=r'([^,]+,)(.*)(?=(,.*))'
    m=re.search(p,str1)
    r=''.join([m.group(1),re.sub(r',',r'_',m.group(2)),m.group(3)])
    print r
```

output: str1 = '$2a$10$.XfjKl/,abcd, 1, ##, s, for free,2-3-4'

Split the string in to three using the regex and then replace all the occurance of ',' with '_' using re.sub()

Answer (score 1):

First replace all dot with line, then replace first and last line with dot.

```
import re
line = '$2a$10$.XfjKl/,abcd, 1, ##, s, for free,2-3-4'
#replace all dot with line
pat_all_dot = re.compile(r',')
line = pat_all_dot.sub('_', line)
#replace first line with dot
line = re.sub(r'_', ',' ,line, count = 1)
#replace end line with dot
line = re.sub(r'(_)([\S]*?)$', r',\2', line) # '$2a$10$.XfjKl/,abcd_ 1_ ##_ s_ for free,2-3-4'
```